# How to add a People Picker SPField to a SPList in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-api

Looking for a snippet of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "People picker" control is used by SP when a column is of type User

so, the following snippet will add one such column:

```
using (SPWeb oWebsite = SPContext.Current.Site.AllWebs["MySite"])
{
    SPFieldCollection collFields = oWebsite.Lists["MyList"].Fields;
    collFields.Add("MyField", Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType.User, false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I kept missing the SPFieldTYpe.User.  Duh.

Comment: can I have JSOM equivalent of this code? I dont have VS  installed on my dev server, we have access to JavaScript only.